# Using library from npm package @google/maps for Ionic 2 project?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, angular, ionic2

this could be silly question from newcomer, but I wonder about can I use Node.js library with stack that Ionic 2 *(Node package system with package.json , Angular 2, Cordova*) provides. I found interesting for my project [library from Google](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) *( I need geocoding for some form validation).* 
For this moment I added this package to `package.json` with

> npm install @google/maps --save
>   npm i

I created provider for client consuming, added

> import {} from '@google/maps';

and understood that I need some sort of *typings* for TS:) Is it really an option to use separate from Ionic and Angular libraries or am I wasting my time?

Update
Thanks to @Ivaro18, I managed how to add typings to my project:

> npm install @types/google-maps --save
>   Now I can make something like this:

```
import GoogleMapsLoader = require('google-maps');
GoogleMapsLoader.URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js';
GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
GoogleMapsLoader.LIBRARIES = ['geocode()', 'places'];
GoogleMapsLoader.CLIENT = 'yourclientkey';
GoogleMapsLoader.CHANNEL = 'myChannel';
GoogleMapsLoader.LANGUAGE = 'fr';
GoogleMapsLoader.REGION = 'GB';
GoogleMapsLoader.VERSION = '3.14';
GoogleMapsLoader.WINDOW_CALLBACK_NAME = '__google_maps_api_provider_initializator__';


@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsClientProvider {


  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello GoogleMapsClientProvider Provider');
    GoogleMapsLoader.createLoader();
    };



}
```

I found about this [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/google-maps/google-maps-tests.ts) but I'm not sure how to use this stuff,e.g.

```
  GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
  GoogleMapsLoader.CLIENT = 'yourclientkey';
```

What is what? Someone tried this lib before? My mandatory task is to use geocoding for address validation.

Comment: `typings install @google-maps --save`?

Comment: The use of external libraries **is** possible in `ionic2`, just a little bit more work than a plain `angular2` application

Comment: @Ivaro18 thanks for response I got message `Unable to find "@google-maps" ("npm") in the registry.` . Could you give me some link on guide for such usage?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/ Turns out it was `npm install @types/@google-maps` **note** if this doesn't work you must create/install a `.d.ts` file, but this might work already

Comment: @Ivaro18 thank you very much. I'll try this.